# How to pass a function input parameter with 50k characters without ORA-01704 error?

Tags: sql, oracle, function

Getting ORA-01704: string literal too long error while passing more than 40k characters to a Function input parameter.

I have an requirement to pass around 50k characters to a function as input parameter. I tried CLOB instead of varchar2 and object type too, but still I am getting string literal too long error.

Can you please help me to pass 50k characters as function input parameter.

```
create or replace function f_abc(
    ids in varchar2  --tried CLOB too
    --INID_CHECK IN CHECK_TYP   --Tried object type too
    )
  return varchar2
is
  return_value varchar2(32000);
  countt number(2);
begin

    for i in (select trim(regexp_substr(ids, '[^,]+', 1, level)) prm from dual connect by level <= regexp_count(ids, ',')+1)
    --FOR i IN 1 .. INID_CHECK.count
    loop
        countt:=0;
        begin
        select count(*)
        into countt
        from x.names
        where name = i.prm  
        and ind='Y';
        if countt = 0 then
            begin
            select count(*)
            into countt
            from x.rt_names
            where name = i.prm  
            and ind='Y';
            if countt = 0 then
                return_value := return_value||','||i.prm 
                ;
            end if;
            end;
        end if;
        end;
    end loop;
if return_value = '' then
    return '';
else
    return return_value;
end if;
```

end;

Comment: Where are you getting the error?  In defining the function?  Or in calling the function?  From your description, it sounds like you're getting an error calling the function but you don't show us how you are calling the function so it's a bit hard to help.  Or are you getting the error from inside the function?  Probably on the line where you are concatenating strings together inside the loop?

Comment: Hi, I am executing the Function passing around 50k characters then i am getting below error.

[Error] Execution (65: 32): ORA-01704: string literal too long

select f_abc('35368001,40295595,40295633,40295753'....) from dual.

Comment: OK.  So line 65 is the line in your code where you're calling the function?  You can't have a string literal longer than 32k.  The function needs to take a `clob` and you need to assemble the `clob` in the caller before passing the `clob` to the function.

Comment: Right, i have tried CLOB too in the Function but still i am getting same error. As you mentioned 'can't have a string literal longer than 32k' but i have an requirement to pass 50k characters... is there any chance to pass 50k to meet my requirement?

Comment: Yes, as I said, the caller of the function would need to assemble a `clob` and pass that to the function.  The caller could choose to assemble the `clob` using two 25k string literals if you wanted.  Though I'd seriously question the wisdom of having a string literal anywhere near that long.  Those values come from somewhere, hopefully a table, so having them hard-coded seems like a bad idea.